# graphql: adding a field to a join table

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server, graphcool

I have two sets of records with the following schema

```
type Player {
    id: ID! @unique
    name: String!
    links: [NPC!]! @relation(name: 'linkedNpcs')
}

type NPC {
        id: ID! @unique
        name: String!
        playerLinks: [Player!]! @relation(name: 'linkedNpcs')
}
```

I want to add an additional field to the `linkedNpcs` called `relationType`.

How would I write this in my `types.graphql` file? Each `player-npc` link should contain a unique record, and since it's a many-to-many relationship, it makes sense that this metaData should exist on the join table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered via graphcool forums: https://www.graph.cool/forum/t/adding-a-field-to-a-relation-table-in-prisma/3086/2

thanks @matic!

```
enum RelationType {
  A
  B
  C
}

type Player {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
  links: [PlayerNPC!]! @relation(name: 'linkedPlayer')
}

type PlayerNPC {
  id: ID! @unique

  relationType: RelationType!

  player: Player! @relation(name: 'linkedPlayer')
  npc: NPC! @relation(name: 'linkedNPC')
}

type NPC {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
  links: [PlayerNPC!]! @relation(name: ‘linkedNPC’)
}
```